# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'error in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to open my group project in my windows system. What should i install to to eliminate this error.

I tried to install `pip install django_adminlte_theme`

while i enter this

```
PS D:\stock1\stock_prediction-version2.2\stock> python manage.py runserver
```

it show `-PS D:\stock1\stock_prediction-version2.2\stock> python manage.py runserver`

and

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_adminlte_theme'
```

and

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```